# Prevent memory leaks in template

Tags: c++, templates, memory-leaks

I have template

```
template <class T>
class A
{
  T* t_;
  A(){t_ = new T();}

  void SetItem(T& t)
  {
     t_ = t;
  }

};
```

There are 2 cases with this template class

```
1. A<T> a;
2. A<T*> b;
```

If I invoke two times `SetItem` i.e.

```
a.SetItem(T());
a.SetItem(T());
```

memory will be cleaned properly?

same if I invoke like this:

```
b.SetItem(new T());
b.SetItem(new T());
```

I know that memory will not be cleaned.

Questions:

1. How to make constrain on template that it takes only `T` or `T*` ?
2. If I use template `A<T*>` how to prevent leaks. Should I modify class or take care of it outside?
3. Is there any way to make this work whenever I use `A<T>` or `A<T*>` ?

I think that use of smart pointers or auto pointers is an option. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: Are you using C++11 or C++03?

Comment: None of this code even works correctly, please fix that.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` would be a better bet, saves you tonnes of headaches about whose responsibility it is to delete memory.

Comment: I would try std::auto_ptr and see if you like it. Just make sure that your class documentation lets the user know that class A owns the object and will destroy it. Better yet get them to pass an auto_ptr to the ctor. The auto_ptr will be invalidated when you copy it to your member auto_ptr.

Comment: @userbb - you should accept one of the answers, or people won't bother in future!  : )

Answer (score 4):

The quick answer is, it's up to the person using the class A to clear up heap allocated memory.  If you use a std::list, and store pointers in it, then you (not the list) are responsible for calling delete on them.  Don't try to make your templated container detect pointers and delete them.

I'd imagine if you use class A with a pointer template param then at some point you would call delete on the return from GetItem() (which I assume the class would provide).

(Also, SetItem should take a const T&.)

Comment: So auto_ptr is not good solution? What bad could happen when I use it?

Comment: It's up to the person using your class to manage heap allocated memory - using auto_ptr is one way they could go about it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid leaks, you should have destructor which will `delete`  T when the object `A` is destroyed.

To enable your template to only take pointers you should use type traits.  I'm not quite familiar enough with it to give you an example.

```
 template <class T>
    class A
    {
      T* t_;
     //Set t_ to nullptr, as you are able to pass new T() to SetItem
      A() : t_(nullptr) {}
      ~A() { delete t_; }  // When A is destroyed, t_ will be deleted.
      void SetItem(const T& t)
      {
         t_ = t;
      }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

A is a meaningless class here. The solutions to not make it leak are:

- Use a smart pointer. If your object is going to be shared and you don't know the lifetimes, you can use shared_ptr. If it isn't and your A class owns the object, use unique_ptr.
- Don't use a pointer at all but use an instance of T within your A. This puts restrictions on the type your class A may hold, but the users of your class can make it hold unique_ptr or shared_ptr by putting that in as the parameterized type. An example is vector which takes objects of type T but users can make their vectors take shared_ptr or unique_ptr.
- You must specify if your class takes ownership if the user passes in a pointer. If so your class is really a smart pointer itself.

Which one to use is rather difficult to ascertain in your example as A has no purpose in its existing form.